# Error Database Sqlite Could not open database

Tags: android, eclipse

I triyng to create database and i have this error

```
package it.unimi.di.simplephone;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
  public static final String DBNAME="BILLBOOK";

public DBhelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)  
{
    db= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("Log", null, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String q="CREATE TABLE "+DatabaseStrings.TBL_NAME+
            " ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                DatabaseStrings.FIELD_NOME+" TEXT," +
                DatabaseStrings.FIELD_NUMERO+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(q);
}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{  }

}
```

this is my DBhelper class..

this is my activity class

```
package it.unimi.di.simplephone;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

   private ListAdapter mAdapter = null;

//database
private DBhelper dbhelper;
private Context ctx;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //DATABASE
     dbhelper=new DBhelper(ctx);
     dbhelper.onCreate(db);

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
            CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    String[] columns = new String[] { CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME };
    int[] names = new int[] { R.id.contact_name };

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, c,
            columns, names,
            SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnComponi);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent it=new Intent(MainActivity.this,componi.class);
            startActivity(it);

        }
    });

    Button log = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LastCall);
    log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent itlog=new Intent(MainActivity.this,log.class);
            startActivity(itlog);

        }
    });

}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super .onStart();
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
            CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    String[] columns = new String[] { CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME };
    int[] names = new int[] { R.id.contact_name };

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, c,
            columns, names,
            SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Cursor c = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);
    String phone = c.getString(c
            .getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    //database
    String nome= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

    //database

    db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("nome", nome);
    cv.put("numero", phone);
    try
    {
        db.insert(DatabaseStrings.TBL_NAME, null,cv);
    }
    catch (SQLiteException sqle)
    {

    }

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);



    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



}
```

the error is Could not open database.. but with the function opendatabase in Class helper i create database if not exist..

thanks

Comment: post a stack trace from logcat.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I've noticed:

```
dbhelper=new DBhelper(ctx);
dbhelper.onCreate(db);
```

You should not be calling `onCreate()` of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. This is called by Android the first time this database is being created. Additionally, your crash is probably a `NullPointerException` because you are passing a `null` object to this method; the member field `db` was never initialized.

---

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)  
{
    db= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("Log", null, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String q="CREATE TABLE "+DatabaseStrings.TBL_NAME+
            " ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                DatabaseStrings.FIELD_NOME+" TEXT," +
                DatabaseStrings.FIELD_NUMERO+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(q);
}
```

You've opened a second database file here and added a table to that. But you never create a table in the current database. Is this intentional? If not, you should use the `db` argument that was passed to you when executing your SQL, because that's the one that `SQLiteOpenHelper` is opening for you.

If the second database file IS intentional, it's worth noting that because you have no `SQLiteOpenHelper` for the "Log" database, you can only ever open it with `SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase` and you do not automatically get `onCreate` and `onUpgrade` hooks. If all you need is one table there, then I might suggest having that table in your main database instead.